# How to write the CMakeList file

Tags: cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1 FATAL_ERROR)       
project(WINDOW CXX) 
set(WINDOW_SRCS window.cpp)     
add_executable(Window ${WINDOW_SRCS})       
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)  

find_library(OPENGL_LIB 
    NAMES lGLEW lglfw3 lGL lrt lm ldl lXrandr lXinerama lXxf86vm lXext lXcursor lXrender lXfixes lX11 lpthread lxcb lXau lXdmcp lXi lSOIL lassimp 
    PATHS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
)   

if(OPENGL_LIB)
    target_link_library(Window ${OPENGL_LIB})   
endif()
```

I am trying to write a CMakeList.txt file. I get an error in  the generated Makefile

makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

I've added `tabs` in the beginning of each line. I can't figure out where is wrong

Comment: Please add the commands you type to generate makefiles and build from CMake.

Comment: Also, it may be better to use the find_package() facility, see reference for FindOpenGL here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenGL.html

Comment: The command `cmake .`

Comment: Found no issue while using your code.

Comment: What do you mean you added tabs at the beginning of each line?

Comment: Something else is going on here. That error is the symptom of a corrupt Makefile.

Comment: Could you try to clean `CMakeCache.txt` file and `Makefile` and the directory `CMakeFiles` and if they exists the files `cmake_install.cmake` and `CTestTestfile.cmake`. Now rerun the CMake configuration via `cmake .` again. Then  `make` and tell us. The solution might be just cleaning the cache.

Comment: @roalz It's a very useful advice. Indeed, it's more complicated than I'd expected

Comment: @fedepad that seems the issue. If you presented the solution as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @MiloLu Added my comment as an answer!

Comment: To avoid this kind of problems, a good practice is to use out-of-source builds, basically o not use the same directory for sources and builds, but separate the build and cmake generated files into a different directory. More details here: http://mirkokiefer.com/blog/2013/03/cmake-by-example/ (search "out-of-source")

Comment: I agree with @roalz about doing out-of-source builds. In this way, you will only need to delete one directory to reconfigure CMake from a clean state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't cleaned CMake generated files from the previous CMake configuration run.
Please remove the `CMakeCache.txt` file and `Makefile` and the directory `CMakeFiles` and if they exists the files `cmake_install.cmake` and `CTestTestfile.cmake`.
Now you can rerun the CMake configuration via `cmake .` again.
Then execute `make` and it should be ok.

---

In the answer I haven't attempted to improve your `CMakeLists.txt`, but just to make the issue you are encountering to go away.
Otherwise, as suggested by @roalz, you could use the `find_package()` to find OpenGL.
Another "improvement" could be to use out-of-source builds. In this way all the build results will be contained in one directory with no interference with the source tree. In this case, to start from a clean state and rerun the CMake configuration, you will only need to remove that build directory, and not all the single files created around. This is particularly useful for projects that have nested source directories (more than one level).