# Missing Separator error on makefile, but I know there is not a space/tab issue

Tags: cmake, makefile, fortify

I am trying to compile a makefile for use with Foritfy SCA via the following command:

```
|Fortify: Scanner started { sourceanalyzer -b build_id -verbose make  -f folder/CMakeLists.txt }
```

but I am continuously running into the following error:

```
folder/CMakeLists.txt:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Compiler Output:
folder/CMakeLists.txt:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Compiler execution failed (exit code: 2).
exit(2)
```

I've reduced my makefile to a single line just to test the common tab/space issue, but even with this following file I still get the same error. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
```

At a loss for what the issue is here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fortify SCA has apparently access to information that we don't have access to, like the actual `folder/CMakeLists.txt` file. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41713481/7582247) is your issue?

Comment: The error message makes it sound like something is running `make` directly on `CMakeLists.txt`. That's not going to work.

Comment: @You Why can't make be run directly on the CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: @colm Because `make` uses `Makefile`s, not `CMakeLists.txt` files (which are something *CMake* uses). You need to run `cmake` to generate `Makefile`s on which you can then run `make`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Apologies for the confusion, wasn't clear in my original post. The single "cmake_minimum..." line at the end is the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Did you also clean up like shown in the link I shared?

Comment: @You I see, ty for the clarification.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah the cache file was hidden in a folder I only now see. Ty for the help!

Comment: @colm Great! You're welcome! I'm voting to close it as a duplicate of that question then.

Comment: Just to clarify, this: `make -f folder/CMakeLists.txt` is wrong.  As mentioned above you can't run make on a cmake input file, just like you can't give a C++ source file to a python interpreter.